# Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, support

I'm a little confused, what is the difference between Stack Overflow and this (Stack Exchange)?

I ask because I asked a question (thinking it was the right place) and I was wrong.

(A little more of a description somewhere would be nice on the site, or maybe I'm and idiot and missed it :) )

Comment: _"A little more of a description somewhere would be nice on the site"_ You mean like [help]? Also, all sites have a [tour] which explains what the site and Stack Exchange are all about.